# .Net Core 5 Web Api - Xunit not reading my appsettings.Development

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, webapi

I'm starting to build tests from my api and for that I'm using xunit, but it's not reading my appsettings.Development.json, what's wrong?

```
namespace CorporateMembership.Test.Integration
{
    public class ContestTest
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public ContestTest()
        {
            var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseEnvironment("Development")
                .UseStartup<Startup>());

            _httpClient = server.CreateClient();
        }...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default when you create `TestServer` it doesn't build configuration and you need to build configuration and pass it to the test server.

```cs
public class ContestTest
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public ContestTest()
    {
        var environment = "Development";
        var directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(directory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json");

        var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment(environment)
            .UseConfiguration(configurationBuilder.Build())
            .UseStartup<Startup>());

        _httpClient = server.CreateClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Allan Your welcome and if you hit the upvote button it makes glad

Comment: I nedd 15 points reputation to click on upvote, now I have only 3, sorry :(

Comment: No problem, now you have 13 ;-), and if you edit questions and improve them then you get some reputations as well.

Comment: OMG Thanks ... I make a new question, I lose 1 day trying make a post test case but don't have success :(

Answer (score 0):

Your test project is likely built into a different directory than your main project, so your appsettings.Development.json file is not there.

[Load your settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) with `IConfigurationBuilder` in your `Startup`. You can specify a relative path there through `AddJsonFile` method.

Also do you really need to start a server in your unit test? You test class functionality, which rarely needs a running server. In order to inject test settings into a class test you could use [the options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and than in your test provide dummy settings via `Options.Create(new MyDummySettings())`.